# How to change multiselect default comma(,) separated behaviour to Dot (.) separated?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown with multiselect and I want to get values by dot(.) separated

P.S. I'm getting value by form collection to the controller.

This is how I am currently getting values:

[image]

the values shown in above image got from 2 different multi-selects,30,32 from 1st one other 13 from other one..so i want to get it like **30.32,13**.......so that i can differentiate between dropdowns

Is there any way to change default behavior of multiselect to change from `,` to `.` ?

multiselect code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.JobStaffId, selectListItems1,new { @class = "form-control js-select js-noFilter hidden DDStaff DD2 ",multiple="multiple", size = "2", @name="JobStaffNm" + t,Id = "JobStaffId" + t })
```

[image]

Comment: `and i want to get data by dot(.` what does this mean exactly, what data, how do you want it, how do you want to access it, ect ect ect ect ect

Comment: instead of getting comma (,) separated i want dot (.) separated values

Comment: check my edit @er-mfahhgk

Comment: Why do you have two different multi-select drop-downs with the same name?

Comment: see my edit @madreflection

Comment: Ok. can you please suggest me how to implement this  @er-mfahhgk

Comment: why you deleted your comment @madreflection

Comment: I thought it was confusing the issue rather than helping.

Comment: i was trying this @madreflection,

Comment: Make the "item" part an array, so you have `item[0].jobStaffId`, `item[1].jobStaffId`, and so on. Then use `formCollection.GetValues("item[0].jobStaffId")`, etc. to get each row's values.

Comment: Thanx @madreflection that solved my problem

Comment: Oh good, glad to hear that. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this! because `multi-select` values pass into controller method as array. So what you can do you change in controller method as follows:

```
dotSeparatedJob = job.Replace(',','.');
```

Comment: No i dont want to change here at controller..i want to get dot separated values from view page

Comment: You cannot do this! because multi-select value pass into controller method as array.

Comment: the values shown in above image got from 2 different multi-selects,30,32 from 1st one other 13 from other one..so i want to get it like **30.32,13**.......so that i can differentiate between dropdowns

Comment: Why ask the question with incomplete information? Update the question with your exact information and tell what you exactly wanting.

Comment: @SumitS. I see its coming from only `JobStaffId` and you are telling it from two different multiselect. How?

Comment: i am getting this values from form collection which does not collects data by id.
+t appended with JobStaffId makes it unique dropdown ..but at form collection we gets all the values from all the dropdowns present inside the form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187410/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-sumits).

Comment: Check the chat please!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
var output = String.Join('.', input.Split(','));  //--> 30.32.13
```

Comment: the values shown in above image got from 2 different multi-selects,30,32 from 1st one other 13 from other one..so i want to get it like **30.32,13**.......so that i can differentiate between dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

If you want to differentiate between dropdowns, please consider adding the ID attribute to each dropdown. Then, when you pass it to your backend, wherever that maybe, you can always get unique selections per ID.

I just scrolled up and saw that you already have the id attribute enabled. Just differentiate by IDs